# How do I load components synchronously in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a header component which makes a call to fetch the user token and store the user's data. I then have a different component (admin component) that is not a child of the header which relies on the user data to fetch additional data. The issue I'm running into is that the admin component initializes before the header component has finished making it's call for the user, therefore breaking my admin component. In other words, the code execution breaks because the active company has not been set yet by the header. Is there a way to make sure these load synchronously in Angular 6 so that I can avoid this issue?

**header.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  user: any;
  activeCompany: any;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getToken().then((user) => {
      this.user = user;
      this.user.Companies = JSON.parse(this.user.Companies.split('&quot;').join('"'));
      this.authService.getActiveCompany$().subscribe((company: any) => {
        if(!company) {
          let company = this.user.Companies[0]
          this.authService.setActiveCompany$(JSON.stringify(company));
        }
        this.activeCompany = company;
      });
    });
  }

  setActiveCompany(company) {
    this.authService.setActiveCompany$(company)
  }
}
```

**admin.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TagService } from '../../services/tag.service';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.css']
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {
  companyId: number;
  tags: any;
  loading: boolean = true;

  constructor(
    private tagService: TagService,
    private authService: AuthService
   ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getActiveCompany$().subscribe((company: any) => {
      // The line below breaks because the active company has not been set yet by the header 
      this.companyId = company.Id
      this.tagService.getTags(companyId).then((tags) => {
        this.setTags(tags)
        this.loading = false;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, Subject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { AppConfig } from '../../app-config';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private activeCompany$: Subject<any>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private _config: AppConfig) {
    let initialActiveCompany;
    if (window.localStorage.getItem('activeCompany')) {
      initialActiveCompany = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('activeCompany'));
}   else {
      this.getToken().then((user: any) => {
        initialActiveCompany = user.Companies = JSON.parse(user.Companies.split('&quot;').join('"'))[0];
  });
}
this.activeCompany$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(initialActiveCompany);
```

}

```
  getToken() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get(`${this._config.API_URL}/Token`).subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);},
        err => {
        console.log("Error retrieving token", err);
      });
    });
  }

  // Returns the observable (read-only) part of this subject
  getActiveCompany$(): Observable<any> {
    return this.activeCompany$.asObservable();
  }

  // Stores the new company value in local storage and pushes it to the subject
  setActiveCompany$(company: any) {
    window.localStorage.setItem('activeCompany', JSON.stringify(company));
    this.activeCompany$.next(company);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can easily deal with this by using the Ngrx Store and Effects, are you already using that in your project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should organize your services little bit more for handling asynchronicity.

You should make the `activeCompany` as `BehaviorSubject` in the AuthService, and then subscribe for change in admin.

Because you need to call the `getTags()` whenever the `activeCompany` is changed.

Comment: You're right. I was under the assumption that a `subject` would only hold out on the first value. Now I know it only reacts to active subscribers when `next()` is called.

Comment: @Silvermind But the code which you had written was correct, just it needs to BehaviorSubject.

Comment: But the problem remains for the op. The value that will immediately emit will be the default value of the BehaviorSubject, which will probably be null, or do you have another suggestion for that initial value problem? Maybe `empty()` will prevent the trigger, but I have not tested it.

Comment: you can put one if condition like  `<admin-component *ngIf="company"></admin-component>`

Comment: Sunil, I'm using ng router <router-outlet> tags to render the admin component so the tag is never used

Comment: <lib-library>
  <app-header></app-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</lib-library>

Comment: router outlet should definitely be lower but whatever, just nest admin within another component and then you can put the if on the parent which the router will load.

Comment: @VivekKumar I have activeCompany set up as a Behavior Subject but this didn't fix the issue for the initial render of the component

Comment: @smooth Can you please share some code snippet. What is the exact error you are facing?

Answer (score 3):

I'd advise that you use a resolver service in your admin component. First create a new resolver service using **ng g s resolver** command in your cli then use this code

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import {
  Resolve,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot
} from "@angular/router";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class ResolverService implements Resolve<any> {
  this.companyId: any;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any> {
    return this.authService.getActiveCompany$().subscribe((company: any) => {
    this.companyId = company.Id
    this.tagService.getTags(companyId).then((tags) => {
    this.setTags(tags)
    this.loading = false;
    });
   });
  }
}
```

and then add this to your routes-module under your admin component

```
{
 path: "admin",
 component: AdminComponent,
 resolve: {
 result: ResolverService
 }
}
```

and then finally in your admin component import **ActicatedRoute**

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
```

and add to your constructor

```
userData = null // store the data you want from your authService here from your resolver

constructor(private actr: ActivatedRoute) {
 this.actr.data.pipe(map(data => data.resuslt)).subscribe(res => {
 this.userData = res;
 });
}
```

I didn't have time to read through your authservice.ts but i hope you get the concept

Answer (score 0):

did you try to implement the safe navigation operator instead? With a little bit of re-organization you could achieve the result of *waiting the result to arrive to actually render the value*.

`The current hero's name is {{currentHero?.name}}`

You can see the [docs here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator).

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare a flag variable
2. After the header component has finished making it's call for the user, set a flag's value to true.
3. Using `*ngIf` load admin component if the value of flag is `true`.